# Computer will not run live cd. Just boots into grub recovery

Tags: boot, live-usb, grubrescue

Okay,
So I am definitely a noob, but I got really tired of ubuntu not allowing me to suspend without hard blocking my wifi, so I went ahead and tried to install opensuse to see if the problem was just ubuntu, but that failed because I couldn't figure out the installation process. So then I proceeded to try and install kali, just to see if it would let my internet work. Well, when I installed kali, I got most of the way through, but towards the end of the installation it said that the installation was complete and to make sure I remove the usb before rebooting. So I clicked out of that screen, but my installation was only at 61%, I gave it 30 minutes hoping it would just complete, but it didn't, so I just pulled out my usb (probably made a few of you cringe there, sorry). So I figured, well crap, now I've probably messed up big time, so I decided to try and go back to ubuntu with my ubuntu live usb. Now here is where my problem is, any time I try to run my ubuntu live usb, It boots into the kali image screen (where it asks if you want to run live or install) but will not effectively run anything from there. I can't boot into live or anything. So to try and solve this, I used my kali live usb, but it won't even go back to the image screen, it just boots to grub recovery from there.

I'm sure I messed up big time and I'm wondering if I can just wipe my computer and start fresh. I have everything backed up that I need, so I'm not worried about any data. Thank you!

Comment: If you are not worried about data loss a fresh install is always recommend. I would of course check BIOS -> Boot menu and check if USB is first boot option.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able/do you know how to access the boot options menu on your computer? If you have your live USB plugged in, and power on your machine while holding/repeatedly pressing the right key (on my computer it is `F12`, but that will differ depending on manufacturer), you should be able to access the boot menu and select your live USB. (I would have simply posted this as a comment, since I am not sure if it will help, but my rank isn't high enough to comment, and I wanted to try to help anyway, since I have been in a similar situation).

Answer (score 0):

if you're worried about data inside your USB, plug it in to another computer and copy to that computer

then you use make installation USB with it (unetbootin)